# Jar file can't load jasper file on a different pc

Tags: java

I have created a netbeans application which uses ireport 5.6.0 for generating report. I have included all necessary libaries for the project. After the creation of the jar file, everything works perfect on my machine but after putting it on a another pc, the jasper report does not work. when i click on the print button, nothing shows.

Code for the print button :

```
try{
                Map param=null;
                InputStream is=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Report/Inward.jrxml");
                JasperDesign jd=JRXmlLoader.load(is);
                JasperReport jasreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("source");
                JRTableModelDataSource Ds = new JRTableModelDataSource(Inward_LogTable.getModel());
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasreport, param,Ds);
                JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint,false);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Any help will do. Thank you

Comment: do you really want an absolute path `"/Report/Inward.jrxml"`?

Comment: if that will help solve the problem,

Comment: Everything works find on my machine but when i  try to run it on a different machine the jasper report file does not load.. The report is stored in a folder called report within the src folder of the project

Comment: Honestly speaking i don't really know what the problem may be. Any suggestion will do..Please!!!.

Comment: @Lino what is wrong with that resource path? You do realize it is not absolute file path right?

Comment: You need to provide console output - most likely stacktrace will be there.

Comment: Please double check that it is actually working locally outside of IDE.